# Mapping a Collection without using DBRef (Spring Data MongoDB)

Tags: mongodb, mapping, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I've been reading a lot that the use of DBRef for Collection Mapping in Spring Data/MongoDB is discouraged. So, how can I implement a mapping that stores an array of ObjectId taken from those objects inside the *students* collection?

Assuming that I have the following POJO model:

```
@Document (collection = "courses")
public class Course {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String name;

    private List<Student> students = new LinkedList<Student>();

    //.. constructors, getters and setters ..
}

public interface CourseRepository extends MongoRepository<Course, String> { }
```

The result should be something like this:

```
courses
{
    _id : ObjectId("foo"),
    _class: "model.Course",
    name: "MongoDB for Dummies",
    students: [ ObjectId("foo2"), ObjectId("foo3"), ... ]
}
```

Instead of this:

```
courses
{
    _id : ObjectId("foo"),
    _class: "model.Course",
    name: "MongoDB for Dummies",
    students: [ 
             DBRef("student", ObjectId("foo2")),
             DBRef("student", ObjectId("foo3"))
    ]
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might wanna try the obvious and change `students` to a `List<ObjectId>`. ;)

Comment: That's pretty ok! That solves the issue for having an array of ObjectId. But in that case, **my POJO model is affected by the db model**; my Course objects will no longer have a list of Student objects inside. Maybe I'm looking at this from a wrong point of view, but isn't a disadvantage removing the List<Student>?

Comment: Should I use a List<ObjectId> studentsIds, and a @Transient List<Student> students?? Please slap me with knowledge! lol

Comment: No further answers on this?

Comment: add @DBRef  annotation on top of your `private List<Student> students = new LinkedList<Student>();` thats all you need.